# Win32Exception "The System Cannot Find the File Specified"

Tags: vb.net, file, exception, win32exception

This has been bugging me for 6 hours

How on earth is it solved. I want the program to run a batch file (IP) which is both in resources and in the application path (i.e. bin/debug and /release).

The batch file works when double clicked by itself...

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code. I have tried everything on the internet...

```
**Private Sub Button3_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
Dim OK = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to renew the computer's IP?", "IP Renew?", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
If OK = DialogResult.OK Then
Dim IP As New ProcessStartInfo
IP.FileName = Application.StartupPath & "\IP.bat"
IP.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Process.Start(IP)
End If
End Sub**
```

This is the exception detail:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
ErrorCode=-2147467259
Message=The system cannot find the file specified
NativeErrorCode=2
Source=System
StackTrace:
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Internet_Connection_Availability.Form1.Button3_Click_1(Object sender, EventArgs e) Form1.vb:line 228
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
at Internet_Connection_Availability.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

I was told this forum was the best one out there

Comment: The system can't find the file you specified and I bet if you can see what IP.FileName is you can figure it out.  Try putting MessageBox.Show(IP.FileName ... ) right after you set it.

Comment: Try to monitor the process run using SysInternal's ProcMon. Will show you exactly where your process is looking for `IP.bat`. Knowing that will probably make it easier for you to fix the problem.

Comment: It actually is showing the right location for the file so it is not the file that is the problem!

Comment: Have you verified that permissions are correct?

Comment: Try using breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line

```
Process.Start(IP)
```

to

```
Process.Start("""" & IP & """")
```

I have had the same problem caused by a space in the folder name in the Application.StartupPath